# How to use functional interface returning void?

Tags: java

I have this construction:

```
if (Objects.isNull(user.getMartialStatus())) {
    user.setMartialStatus(MartialStatus.MARRIED);
 }
```

I have many of them, & I want to optimize code using functional interface.
Okay. I write something like this:

```
public static <T> void processIfNull(T o, Supplier<Void> s) {
    if (Objects.isNull(o)) {
        s.get();
    }
}
```

Then, I wait that this code shall work:

```
processIfNull(user.getMartialStatus(), () -> user.setMartialStatus(MartialStatus.MARRIED));
```

But IDEA write:

> void is not compatible with Void

Please, tell me, what to do.

Comment: I don't think `Supplier` is a good interface to use here. You could use `Runnable` if you want, or just define your own functional interface with a single void parameterless method.

Comment: `processIfNull(T o, Runnable r) { r.run(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error explains `Void` is a class which is not equivalent to `void`. `Supplier<Void>` expects to return `Void` like `Supplier<String>` will expect `String` object to return.

So your functional interface should be like below.
It has a `void apply()` which matches the signature of `() -> ...`

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ActionIfNotNull {
    void apply();
}
```

However when you search for an inbuild functional interface, you can come up with `Runnable` as Jon Skeet suggested.

**Solution**

```
public static <T> void processIfNull(T o, Runnable s) { // instead of you Runnable can use your own functional interface like ActionIfNotNull
    if (Objects.isNull(o)) {
        s.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 9 `Optional` has the `ifPresentOrElse` method, which could be used for this.

```java
Optional
    .ofNullable(user.getMartialStatus())
    .ifPresentOrElse(o -> {}, () -> user.setMartialStatus(MartialStatus.MARRIED););
```

You could also replace the `o -> {}` by some `NOOP` Consumer if you like, like this:

```java
private static final Consumer<Object> NOOP = o -> {};

...

Optional
    .ofNullable(user.getMartialStatus())
    .ifPresentOrElse(NOOP, () -> user.setMartialStatus(MartialStatus.MARRIED););
```

Anyway, I think the solution [Trine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3804422/trine) came up with, is preferable, because it makes it much clearer, what's going on.